# how to import global css in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am trying to import global css file inside react javascript file. I am importing in following way:

```
import React from "react";
import MainWrapper from "./components";
import "./global.css";


const App = () => {

  return (
    <MainWrapper />
  );
};


export default App;
```

My global.css file looks like following:

```
@import '/node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css';



i.anticon.anticon-menu-unfold.trigger, i.anticon.anticon-menu-fold.trigger {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 12px;
    color: white;
}
i.anticon.anticon-menu-fold.trigger{
    float: right;
}
```

Here above, I am overidding predefined css of ANT Design. Here it is not able to override ant's  predefined css.

My webpack.config.js looks like following:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const WebapckManifestPlugin = require("webpack-manifest-plugin");


module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
                options: {
                    presets: [
                        "@babel/preset-env",
                        "@babel/preset-react"
                    ],
                    plugins: [
                        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
                        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
                    ]
                }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "html-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.css$/,
      //   use: [
      //     "style-loader"
      //   ,
      //    "css-loader" 
      //   ]

      // }, 
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: 
        [
            {
                loader: "style-loader",
            },
            // {
            //   loader:  "isomorphic-style-loader",
            // },
            {
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                    importLoaders: 1,
                    modules: {
                        localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]

    },
    {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000" }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./public/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new WebapckManifestPlugin({
      template: "./public/manifest.json"
    })
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*",".js",".jsx"]
  }
}
```

However, look below. I am importing css file in below js file. It works

```
import React, { useState }  from "react";
import { Layout, Menu, Icon } from "antd";
// import useStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader/useStyles'
import style from "./style.css";

const Dashboard = () => {
// useStyles(style);
return(
    <div className={style.dashboard}>
        karan
    </div>
    );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

My style.css file looks like this:

```
.dashboard{
    text-align: center;
}
```

I think the problem is with webpack.config.js. 
When I change style syntax from:

```
className={style.dashboard}
```

To:

```
className="dashboard"
```

And import statement from:

```
import style from "./style.css";
```

To:

```
import "./style.css";
```

And webpack.config.js  **test: /.css$/** to:

```
{
         test: /\.css$/,
         use: [
           "style-loader"
         ,
          "css-loader" 
         ]

       }
```

Everythings works then.

Comment: try `import styles from "./global.css";`

Comment: Can you elaborate on the _not able to override_ part? Does the styles appear in the browser? Is it a specificity issue?

Comment: @GibboK ,  No it is still not working

Comment: @Agney, ant design has pre defined classes for example className = "ant-layout-sider". I was able to override them in global.css file and imported that file like "import   ./global.css" when I used simple css loader. When I added options to css loader in webpack.config.js, it was then not able to override css from global.css

Comment: @karan02 please try to use this in your webpack.config and let me know?
`localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]'`

Comment: @GibboK, No still it is not working

Comment: @GibboK , in my global css, line import '/node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css'; works applies css to file but css code after that line doesn't works